# How Do I Assign LDAP Password Via LDAPjs?

Tags: node.js, ldap, ldapjs

I'm using `ldapjs`.

I got this code from some sites:

```
var newUser = {
    cn: 'new guy',
    sn: 'guy',
    uid: 'nguy',
    mail: 'nguy@example.org',
    objectClass: 'inetOrgPerson',
    userPassword: ssha.create('s00prs3cr3+')
}
```

The thing is, the password saved as `OctetString`, and can't be used for login. Do anyone here knows how do I assign password using `node` (`ldapjs` preferred)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving in plain text.

Most LDAP server implementations expect to receive the password in plain text and the server will then encrypt the password.

There are dependencies on the LDAP server implementation and configuration.

-jim

Oh, You did not mention it was AD. Active directory is quite different. It uses `[unicodePwd][1]`, not `userPassword.` Password operations must be over an encrypted connection. And finally, the password must be "text value in UTF-16". Those Quotes are required.

See [updateUserPassword](https://github.com/jwilleke/Examples-JNDI/blob/master/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/ADConnection.java) for the JNDI (Java) code for this.

Comment: Same, Jim, AD will treat it as text field.

Comment: Oh, You did not mention it was AD.

Comment: Sorry, then. After some good reads I got my answer yesterday. Ended up setting LDAPS, haha. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Hey bentinata what was the solution? I tried the last comment on this github link https://github.com/ldapjs/node-ldapjs/issues/342
but still getting the following error
problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0